# Forcing enum field to 8 bits in standard C with bitfields

Tags: c, enums, bit-fields

I saw few questions here about how to force an enum to 8 or 16 bits. The common answer was that it can be done in C++11 or higher. Unfortunately, I don't have that luxury.

So, here is what I'm thinking. I only need the enum to be 8 bits when it's in a struct whose size I want to minimize. So:

**Option A:**

```
typedef enum { A, B, C, MAX = 0xFF } my_enum;

struct my_compact_struct
{
    my_enum field1 : 8; // Forcing field to be 8 bits 
    uint8_t something;
    uint16_t something_else;
};
```

I think most or all optimizers should be smart enough to handle the 8 bitfield efficiently.

**Option B:**

Not use an enum. Use typedef and constants instead.

```
typedef uint8_t my_type;

static const my_type A = 0;
static const my_type B = 1;
static const my_type C = 2;

struct my_compact_struct
{
    my_type field1; 
    uint8_t something;
    uint16_t something_else;
};
```

Option A is currently implemented and seems to be working, but since I want to do (now and in the future) what's correct now and not just what's working, I was wondering if option B is clearly better.

Thanks,

Comment: (A) won't minimize the field. It will only make 8 bits of the whole field usable

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Which do you use?

Comment: Your question states "Standard C" but your tags include "c++". Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using C. Will edit.

Comment: You cannot do this in *standard* C, no. In C++ it is possible since C++11.

Comment: It is a bad idea to use variables as constant masks. `const` does not introduce a constant in C. Use `#define`s` or an `enum`. Apart from that the second approach is fine.

Comment: @StoryTeller will it matter if I guarantee that my enum values are at most 0xFF?

Comment: Nope. The underlying type for any enum in C is an int.

Comment: Sidenote: use self-explanatory names for the constants, best prefixed with the name of the type they relate to.

Comment: Long story short, keep the enum. Make the field a `uint8_t` and document where the set of flags is to be taken from. There's little point defining the field as `my_enum` since `A | B` does not produce a value listed in the enumeration.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Agreed, that works for `uint8_t`, because an `int` is always larger. It already causes problems for `uint16_t` if you need the full range.

Comment: @Olaf so this approach will better than typedef + defines (option B)?

Comment: @EladWeiss At some point, you can't use `enum`s, so `typedef`+ constant-marcros is more consistent if you have multiple such constructs. But I'm split in halves and I use both. As a personal note: I can't understand why the C commitee did not allow `enum`s to specify the tape similar to C++11 does. It would not break legacy code, but would make `enum`s really usable for embedded programming for the first time. It is worse, because embedded is the major field to use C.

Comment: @Olaf - The C++11 change was probably done to "steal market share" from C in the embedded world.

Comment: @StoryTeller: My point is not why C++ did add this, but my C11 did **not**. Would have been a minor addition, not much complicate to add to compilers. But likely the same reason why VLAs were made optional (against the commitee's mantra of backwards-compatibility: some commercial compiler vendors wanted to make money with the least effort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your specific values in an `enum` can fit into a smaller type than an `int`, then a C implementation is free to choose the underlying type of the `enum` to be a smaller type than an `int` (but the type of the `enum` constants in this case will be `int`). But there is *no way* you can force a C compiler to use a type smaller than an `int`. So with this in mind and the fact that an `int` is at least 16 bits, you're out of luck.

But `enum`s in C are little more than debugging aids. Just use an `uint8_t` type if you compiler has it:

```
static const uint8_t something = /*some value*/
```

If not then use a `char` and *hope* that CHAR_BIT is 8.

Comment: The implementation is free to choose a smaller type for an `enum`. But the constants are **always** `int`. And `const` does not qualify a constant. C has no symbolic constants other than `enum-constants` (which are indeed near useless if you need any other type than `int`)

Comment: @Olaf: Remind me never to take the opposing side to you in a pub quiz.

Comment: Interesting... a former boss of mine said something very similar :-)

Answer (score 4):

Step into same problem, I solved it this by using `__attribute__((packed))`. Packed align data to 4 Bytes, with `packed` `(int)sizeof(my_compact_struct) = 4`, without `packed` `(int)sizeof(my_compact_struct) = 8`

```
typedef enum __attribute__((packed)){ 
A = 0x01
B = 0x10
C = 0x255 // Max value, or any other lower than this
} my_enum;

struct my_compact_struct __attribute__((packed)){
    my_enum field1 : 8; // Forcing field to be 8 bits 
    uint8_t something;
    uint16_t something_else;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Option B would be best.  You'd be defining the type in question to be a known size, and the `const` values you define will also be the correct size.

While you would lose out on the implicit numbering of an `enum`, the explicit sizing of the field and its values makes up for it.

Comment: The `const` values are not constants, though. An `enum` for the constants or `#define`s are better. (I recommend the latter, because you can specify the type).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enum` or even `typedef enum` like a grouped `#define`. Do not actually define a structure member, data stream, or global variable as type `enum`. Rather define all storage members as fixed types like `uint8_t`. As if you used `#define` just set them to the `enum` literal constants. If you use any kind of lint tool, then this design style will raise some messages which you will need to tailor. Just like malformed `#define` if the literal value doesn't fit, then bad things can happen, and either way you need to pay attention. In a debugger or hardware simulator, the `enum` can provide useful display reference information. Temporary variables are an exception to how global definitions are treated. For function parameters or automatic variables, and only then, define them with the `enum` type. In this context `int` is going to be the most efficient word size as well as the standard behavior of `enum`. There is no error possible nor hyper-optimizing you can do.